# how to remove nested loops using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sqlcmd = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE category='$category'";
$temp = mysql_query($sqlcmd);
while ( $value = mysql_fetch_array($temp) ) {
  $sqlcmd = "SELECT SUM(quantity) AS pending 
            FROM withdrawals 
            WHERE item_code='$value[item_code]' 
            AND withdraw_number IN ( 
                SELECT withdraw_number 
                FROM withdrawal_number 
                WHERE is_dispatched=0 AND (series_type='DC' OR series_type='D') )";
  $temp2 = mysql_query($sqlcmd);
  $value2 = mysql_fetch_array($temp2);
}
```

i tried changing to this but it doesn't give me the same results:

```
$sqlcmd = "SELECT i.item_code, i.item_category, i.item_description, i.quantity, i.reorder_point, SUM(w.quantity) AS pending 
            FROM inventory i, withdrawals w, withdrawal_number wn 
            WHERE i.item_code=w.item_code 
            AND w.withdraw_number=wn.withdraw_number 
            AND i.category='Store' 
            AND wn.is_dispatched=0 
            GROUP BY i.item_code, wn.withdraw_number";
$temp = mysql_query($sqlcmd);
while ( $value = mysql_fetch_array($temp) ) {
}
```

Comment: Learn to use ANSI JOIN syntax instead of cross-products.

Comment: You're missing the `series_type` criteria in the second query. And you have `i.category = 'Store'` instead of `i.category = '$category'`.

Comment: You also need to use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to get zero sums for items that have no withdrawals.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `series_type` check in your second query. And if you want to get zero sums, you need to use `LEFT JOIN`.

And you shouldn't include `withdraw_number` in the `GROUP BY`, since you weren't grouping by that in the original query, it's just used to filter.

```
$sqlcmd = "SELECT i.*, IFNULL(pending, 0) AS pending 
        FROM inventory i
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT item_code, SUM(pending) AS pending
            FROM withdrawals w
            JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT withdraw_number
                  FROM withdrawal_number 
                  WHERE dispatched = 0 AND series_type IN ('DC', 'D')
            ) AS wn ON w.withdraw_number=wn.withdraw_number
            GROUP BY item_code
        ) AS w ON i.item_code=w.item_code 
        WHERE i.category='$category'";
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` is needed in the innermost subquery to prevent multiplying the sum by the number of rows with the same `withdraw_number`.

You should also stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They've been deprecated for years, and removed completely in PHP 7. You should use `mysqli` or `PDO`, and use prepared statements with parameters instead of substituting variable into the SQL.

Comment: i keep getting errors. im using MySQL 5.0.24a, maybe LEFT JOIN is not supported?

Comment: I forgot an alias for one of the subqueries. Was the error "Every derived table must have an alias"?